# Deauthorize an op from using /kill and /tp commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I went on my realm and my friend was trolling me with `/kill` in command blocks and chat. He also kept teleporting to me so his head was inside mine, so I couldn't break his command blocks.

How can I stop him (without taking away his op)?  Is it possible?

Comment: You could blacklist him on the server.

Comment: Also general tip on friends who you dont have fun playing with: don't play with them.

Answer (score 2):

In the standard Minecraft, the only thing you can do, is to de-op him. You can't limit the commands, a user can execute otherwise. But the commandblocks which he already placed would still be a executed. You can break them by standing on them and using the following command: `/setblock ~ ~-1~ air 0`. This command deletes the block below your feet.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery's answer is correct. I would like to add that this is possible in [Bukkit](https://www.spigotmc.org/) though. Use a permissions manager to do so. I personally use McMyAdmin, since it also adds an interface for the less tech savvy server admins, but you can also use [PermissionsEx](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/). The plugin [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) should give you the opportunity to disable command blocks for a single player.

Note: you did not specify a version. Some of these plugins may not work and require alternatives depending on your version.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are using realms, which does not allow modding.

Comment: I'm using minecraft 1.8.9

Comment: im also using windows 10 Will that Bukkit work for me? if so how can i download it? and do you have a link for me?

Comment: @bigfinfrank A magical machine called Google exists which can find basically everything in the universe.

Answer (score -1):

Teleport go your friend, /kill him then break the command blocks. I don't play realms so I don't know much about it